# Haskell code for reversing string is messed up

Tags: haskell, reverse

I wrote a haskell code that would reverse a general list, for example,
the input is             (P (L M (X Y)) f)
and the output should be (f ((Y X)M L)P)

Yet I couldn't produce the same output.

here's what I got.

```
      [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
     Linking main ...
        Enter something
         (P (L M (X Y)) f)
         Input: "(P (L M (X Y)) f)"
     Output: "(Y X(P ( M L)) f)"
```

Its messed up.

Yet I couldn't produce the same output.

Code

```
reverseGroups :: String -> String
reverseGroups [] = []
reverseGroups ('(':xs) = "(" ++ reverseInner xs []
where
reverseInner :: String -> String -> String
reverseInner [] acc = reverseGroups acc
reverseInner ('(':xs) acc = reverseInner xs ('(':acc)
reverseInner (')':xs) acc = reverseGroups acc ++ ")" ++ reverseGroups xs
reverseInner (x:xs) acc = reverseInner xs (x:acc)
reverseGroups (x:xs) = x : reverseGroups xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
putStrLn "Enter something"
inputString <- getLine
let output = reverseGroups inputString
putStrLn $ "Input: " ++ show inputString
putStrLn $ "Output: " ++ show output
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you break this into three phases: 1. parse the incoming `String` into a tree data type 2. modify the tree 3. pretty print the tree back into a `String`. One benefit of this approach is that it breaks down the problem into smaller problems that can independently be debugged; code that does less is easier to understand and easier to fix.

Comment: Why is your reverse output missing two spaces (I thought it should be `"(f ((Y X) M L) P)"`)? Is that a requirement or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the missing spaces before `M` and `P` are a typo you could just reverse the string and replace the parentheses with their opposite part:

```hs
reverseGroups :: String -> String
reverseGroups = map reverseParens . reverse
    where reverseParens ')' = '('
          reverseParens '(' = ')'
          reverseParens x = x
```

Comment: This solution reminded me of [this code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/convenient-palindrome-checker). :-)